# UIView refresh after comming back from another ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, refresh

On a `Storyboard` I´ve placed a `UIImage` right in the middle of the view.

In `viewDidAppear` I change the position of this UIImage with:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear {
   img.center = CGPointMake(5,5);
    }
```

after starting the ios App on my iPhone the image was shown on position
5.5

when  I change to another `ViewController` and come back to the `viewcontroller` with the image,
the image is placed right in the middle and not on position 5,5

`[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` has no effect

Comment: Can you show the full code. how did u setup imageview (within the class or outlet) and is it strong/weak

Comment: I make the setup by IBOutlet in the @interface section.

Comment: Now i tried it with 2 Images

UIImage1 setup as IBoutlet in the intergface section
UIImage2 setup as @property weak and also 1 time strong IBoutlet

starting the app
UIImage1 was shown in pos 5,5
UIImage2 was never in pos 5,5

Comment: - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {.do it..} is the trick!